# What value does the "Employees" tag show?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Convince me the [employees](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employees) is worth keeping.

It seems too vague to really matter, since most questions here are about employees, and the tag can't really provide any meaningful additional information.

To save you some searching time, here is the full tag wiki:

> Questions relating to the people who work for a company

Comment: Kill it! Burn it with Fire! Drop the remains in Acid along with anyone who tries to use it again in the future... ok the last part may have been overboard.

Answer (score 8):

I believe a tag as general as "employees" is useless.

Since this is workplace.stackexchange, "employees" is implied in pretty much every question. You might as well have a "work" tag.

If tags are to be of any real benefit, they must be discriminatory. That is, selecting a tag must exclude a majority of unrelated questions. I can't see that happening if "employee" were used as defined in the tag wiki.

Comment: Tag removal is a good time to go through and clean up some questions. Scrolling to the bottom of [this list of results](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=votes&q=%5bemployees%5d%20votes%3a-15) shows you the worst questions with this tag, if anyone wants to go through some of them.

Comment: yes can we also look at the "employer relations" tag as a semi professional in this area I would have said the term, is "employee relations" or "industrial relations"